# sql server agent job frequency set to 3 seconds

Tags: sql-server-agent

I would like to setup a SQL Server agent job to run every 3 seconds, but I found that the minimum frequency is 10 seconds.

Then I try to setup multiple schedules, such that first schedule starts at 00:00 (run every 10 seconds), second schedule starts at 00:03 (run every 10 seconds), third schedule starts at 00:06 (run every 10 seconds).

But the second schedule and third schedule never runs, I have googled that the sql server agent job needs 5 seconds idle time before the next schedule starts

Is there any idea how I can set the sql server agent job to run in every 3 seconds?

Thanks.

Comment: How long does the job take to run? And what job do you need to run so often?

Comment: Send SMS through API call

Comment: probably the wrong tool for the job. SQL Server is not a generalized scripting application, it's a database server. I suggest you write something in Powershell, C# or Python and setup a scheduled task or cronjob for it

Answer (score 0):

you can write this in a step and it will do something you want to in every 3 sec while job runs

while 1=1
step which you want to execute
waitfor '00:00:03'  --3 sec

Comment: Please use four spaces to include pre-formatted code examples in your answer.